# Representing the learned weights of MNIST using Tensorflow graphically

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I was tinkering with the tutorial [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) on Tensorflow and I am trying to represent the learned weights using the multilayer convolution network in an image.
The above tutorial has a simpler one, [MNIST For ML Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) that shows this image representing the learned weights of the trained model.

[image: Weights of MNIST in Tensorflow tutorial]

**This is my code:**

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as ran
import tensorflow as tf

def TRAIN_SIZE(num):
    print ('Total Training Images in Dataset = ' + str(mnist.train.images.shape))
    print ('--------------------------------------------------')
    x_train = mnist.train.images[:num,:]
    print ('x_train Examples Loaded = ' + str(x_train.shape))
    y_train = mnist.train.labels[:num,:]
    print ('y_train Examples Loaded = ' + str(y_train.shape))
    print('')
    return x_train, y_train

def TEST_SIZE(num):
    print ('Total Test Examples in Dataset = ' + str(mnist.test.images.shape))
    print ('--------------------------------------------------')
    x_test = mnist.test.images[:num,:]
    print ('x_test Examples Loaded = ' + str(x_test.shape))
    y_test = mnist.test.labels[:num,:]
    print ('y_test Examples Loaded = ' + str(y_test.shape))
    return x_test, y_test

def display_digit(num):
    print(y_train[num])
    label = y_train[num].argmax(axis=0)
    image = x_train[num].reshape([28,28])
    plt.title('Example: %d  Label: %d' % (num, label))
    plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray_r'))
    plt.show()

def display_mult_flat(start, stop):
    images = x_train[start].reshape([1,784])
    for i in range(start+1,stop):
        images = np.concatenate((images, x_train[i].reshape([1,784])))
    plt.imshow(images, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray_r'))
    plt.show()

x_train, y_train = TRAIN_SIZE(55000)
display_digit(0)
display_mult_flat(0,400)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
x_train, y_train = TRAIN_SIZE(5500)
x_test, y_test = TEST_SIZE(10000)
LEARNING_RATE = 0.05
TRAIN_STEPS = 1000

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cross_entropy)
for _ in range(TRAIN_STEPS):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

for i in range(10):
    plt.subplot(2, 5, i+1)
    weight = sess.run(W)[:,i]
    plt.title(i)
    plt.imshow(weight.reshape([28,28]), cmap=plt.get_cmap('seismic'))
    frame1 = plt.gca()
    frame1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    frame1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False) 
plt.show()


def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

# First convolution layeer
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

# Second convolution layer
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# Densely Connected Layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

#Dropout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

#Readout Layer
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

#Evaluating the model
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(20000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

for i in range(10):
    plt.subplot(2, 5, i+1)
    weight = sess.run(W_fc2)[:,i]
    plt.title(i)
    plt.imshow(weight.reshape([32,32]), cmap=plt.get_cmap('seismic'))
    frame1 = plt.gca()
    frame1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    frame1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False) 
plt.show()
```

I am printing the image of learned weights at **two times**. 
Once as the output of a simple MNIST algorithm shown in in the tutorial [MNIST For ML Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) and the second time by using multilayer convolution network.
**The 1st output is correct**:
[image: Weights of simple tensorflow mnist algorithm]
However, **The 2nd output** using the Multilayer Convolution Network shown in the tutorial  [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) is this:
[image: Weights of Multilayer Convolution Network using tensorflow mnist algorithm]
**How do I get the 2nd diagram right?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct. This is the weight image of the final layer. The reason why this looks like this is, that you now have 2 fully connected layers on top and the feature representation of the fully connected layer before yours is not remotely similar to the original number or even an image. The feature representation in the 2nd last fully connected layer is an array of 1024 numbers. Therefore by plotting the weights you will not see what you are doing.

Maybe you have more luck by plotting the weights of the convolutional layers. They are at least semantically images. However their size depends on the filter size.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to plot the weights of the convolution layers but I am getting an error because I am reshaping them wrong. In the 1st convolution layer, the weight is `W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])`. In the code for plotting, what should be my reshaped weight `plt.imshow(weight.reshape([x,x]), cmap=plt.get_cmap('seismic'))`. Can you tell me the values of x?

Comment: They are 32 images of size 5 x 5. They will ptobably show an edge detection filter. What most people do is plot the output of the convolutional layer to see what the network uses as intermediate representation.

Comment: I am getting this error. Somehow I am wrongly reshaping the W_conv1 weight `plt.imshow(weight.reshape([5,5]), cmap=plt.get_cmap('seismic'))
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Comment: When trying to find the shape of W_conv1 using this code:                     `for i in range(10):
    plt.subplot(2, 5, i+1)
    weight = sess.run(W_conv1)[:,i]
    
print (weight.shape)`                                                                                           this is the error that I get: _weight = sess.run(W_conv1)[:,i]
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5_

Comment: `weight =(W_conv1)[:,:,1,i]` should be used. Then you should not have to reshape. W_conv1 should have a shape of [5, 5, 1, 32]

Comment: I tried this, but I got this error: _weight = sess.run(W_conv1)[:,:,1,i]
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 1_

Comment: Try weight = sess.run(W_conv1) and outpout the value of weight.shape.

Comment: Yeah the shape is (5, 5, 1, 32)

Comment: Ok, I did the wrong thing with the indexing. You need to use `[:,:,0,i]`. I tried it and it works on my machine. As said those are the filter kernel. They are grayscale values.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very grateful. :) I generated plots for the 2 convolution layers and I must say they aren't much useful either, although better than the plot of the Readout layer. This has been a good learning experience.